# rails 3 : having trouble with routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting the following error: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"events"}

My routes.rb file has the following entry:

```
resources :events
```

My events_controller.rb has the following:

```
 def index
@events = Event.all     
end

def show
@event = Event.find(params[:id])    
end
```

my show events page has the following:

```
<h1>SHOW EVENT DETAILS</h1>
<%= @currevent.name %>
<br/><br/>
<%= button_to "Back",event_path %>
```

Any ideas why I'm getting this error? Thanks in advance!

Forgot to include my index.html.erb for events:

```
<table border="1">
<% @events.each do |event| %>
<tr>    
    <td><%= event.name %></td>
     <td><%= button_to 'Show', event %></td>

</tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br/><br/>
<%= button_to "Back",home_path %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

show page got wrong. there are 2 corrections - 
1. `@curevent` needs to be `@event`
2. `event_path` should be `events_path`

```
<h1>SHOW EVENT DETAILS</h1>
<%= @event.name %>
<br/><br/>
<%= button_to "Back",events_path %>
```

Comment: I figured it out. In addition to these fixes on my home page there was also a link to event_path instead of events_path

Answer (score 1):

You want either `events_path` or `event_path(@event)` I believe.

Comment: I just added my current index page content to the orginal question. I also tried <%= button_to 'Show',event_path(event) %> and <%= button_to 'Show',events_path %> instead and no luck.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `<%= button_to "Back",events_path %>`   (you're missing a 's') to go to the list of events.

`event_path` exists, it is used to show a particular event (the `show` action as stated in the error message, and you should give it an `Event`).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, makes more sense now. I fixed this though and I'm still getting the error.

Comment: @turbo2oh Check the link of your button, it should now be `http://localhost:3000/events`

Answer (score 0):

```
event_path
```

should be

```
events_path
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches. The simplest would be go to a new temporary directory and create a new clean Rails 3 project running the following commands:

```
cd /tmp 
rails new tst 
cd tst 
rails generate scaffold event
```

You can then look at the apps/config/routes.rb, apps/controller/events_controller.rb, and the apps/views/events files to see the how scaffold created file differ from your current code.

Alternatively, you could try to debug your existing code.

At the command line, run `rake routes` to confirm your events controller is set up correctly. you should see a line like this:

```
  event GET    /events/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"events"}
```

This indicates that the correct path to the show controller actually exists and the path to the controller should be `event` in your apps/views/event/index.html.erb code.

When do you get the error? When you are trying to display the events index route?